# PHP: Swap placeholders in string variable for corresponding defined variable values

Tags: php

I have a PHP script with some variables set in the global namespace:

```
$domain = 'example.com';
$hostname = 'www.' . $domain;
```

I am reading an external file into a string variable in my script using [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
$file_contents = file_get_contents('external_file.tpl');
```

The external file (and the string `$file_contents`) contains placeholders which correspond to variable names.

```
127.0.0.1 {{domain}} {{hostname}}
```

I would like to have all the placeholders in the variable `$file_contents` replaced with their respective PHP variables already set. I want this to work generically (without hard-coding placeholder / variable names). I do not want to edit the file, just the contents of the string.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: How would php know what placeholders to replace if you don't want to hard code it and it is in the global namespace?

Comment: @PeeHaa Any string between `{{` and `}}` should be replaced with the corresponding variable. For example, `{{some_var}}` should be replaced with `$some_var`.

Comment: 1) parse the file 2) gets placeholders 3) look into the scope whether a variable exists 4) replace

Comment: And watch out for potential information leaking

Comment: @PeeHaa Exactly. But I'm a little overwhelmed with all the string replacement functions. I'm hoping someone can guide me in the right direction on which would be the best for this task. Also, this is going to need regex and I'm not that strong at regex.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454683/php-find-and-exctract-into-an-array-all-instances-of-specific-text-in-a-string should get you started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright guys, I took some bits and pieces from other answers and came up with what I think is the best solution for me:

```
$domain = 'example.com';
$hostname = 'www.' . $domain;
$file_contents = '127.0.0.1 {{domain}} {{hostname}}';

$result = preg_replace_callback(
    "/{{(.+?)}}/",
    function ($matches) {
        return $GLOBALS[$matches[1]];
    },
    $file_contents
);
```

This answer combines ideas from @TonyDeStefano, @dops, and @fschmengler. So please up-vote them. @BugaDániel also helped with his comments.

Comment: Wouldn't this only replace the first match, but the `preg_replace_callback` gets all matches?

Comment: @dops It seems to be replacing all matches for me.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include $_GLOBALS and that should replace every match in the file with one call.  Am I being dim and missing something?

Comment: Fair enough, I'm not sure why :) but as long as it works

Comment: @dops I think `preg_replace_callback` iterates over each match so there isn't a need for the `foreach` . . . at least it seems to be for me. I stuck an `echo $matches[1];` into the callback and got each instance echoed to me so it seems to be running through them all.

Comment: Actually your regexp - while it works - is semantically wrong. [] denotes a character class, `[^}}]` means the inside can't match `}` characters. While this leads to correct behaviour, it does not only disallow the closing `}}` but any array keys containing `}`. You basically exclude valid (but unlikely) array keys.

Comment: Yes' went back to my test and saw what I had done differently :) I fixed something when I copied my code from phpStorm into the answer and then forgot I'd fixed it :D

Comment: @BugaDániel Would this be better: `/\{\{([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\}\}/` (from @TonyDeStefano).

Comment: Actually, `/{{(.+?)}}/` to disallow empty matches

Comment: Thanks, @BugaDániel. I'll go with that :)

Answer (score 2):

- Parse file for items between {{ and }}
- Check to see if a global variable exists
- Search and replace

Like so:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match('/\{\{([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\}\}/', $file_contents, $matches);

foreach ($matches as $match)
{
    // You might want to check to make sure the variable is a string
    if (isset($GLOBALS[$match]))
    {
        str_replace('{{'.$match.'}}', $GLOBALS[$match], $file_contents);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would probably use preg_replace_callback, but this is a good enough solution where you can also whitelist/blacklist variables.

Comment: @BugaDániel Yeah me too, I've upvoted this but added a `preg_replace_callback` solution to the answer

Answer (score 1):

> **Disclaimer:** I don't think it's a good idea to allow arbitrary variables to be used in whatever this template is going to be.

The function [`get_defined_vars()`](http://php.net/get-defined-vars) creates an array of all currently available variables in the form `variable_name => value` (**THIS INCLUDES SUPERGLOBALS LIKE $_SERVER AND $_GET!**)

The string translation function [`strtr(string $str, array $replace_pairs)`](http://php.net/strtr) can replace keys of an associative array with their values in a string.

Together they form a mighty but dangerous alliance. The following code will replace `domain` with the value of `$domain` and so on:

```
echo strtr(file_get_contents('external_file.tpl'), get_defined_vars());
```

Adding `{{...}}` is possible with a little extra effort:

```
$vars = get_defined_vars();
$replace = array();
foreach ($vars as $key => $value) {
    $replace['{{' . $key . '}}'] = $value;
}
echo strtr(file_get_contents('external_file.tpl'), $replace);
```

---

Use it responsibly! Remember not to trust any user input.

Comment: That is clever. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `preg_replace_callback` to do this, you will need to put your replacements into an array though.

e.g

```
    $domain = 'example.com';



    $newString = preg_replace_callback(
        '/{{([^}}]+)}}/',
        function ($matches) {
            foreach ($matches as $match) {
                if (array_key_exists($match, $_GLOBALS))
                    return $replace[$match];
            }
        },
        $file_contents
    );
```

The matches returned for that particular regex would be an array

```
array [
    '{{hostname}}',
    'hostname',
    '{{domain}}',
    'domain'
]
```

Which is why we would do a check with `array_key_exists`

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do this without having to set up the array? I know that `$matches[1]` in the callback provides the name of the variable.

Comment: This doesn't work, but something along the lines of: `function the_callback($matches) { return ${$matches[1]}; }`.

Comment: @TomDworzanski you can't pass variables easily into the callback function so an array is best. You could set up the array elsewhere using some kind of algorithm though and call this through a function.  I feel this is probably the best answer to solving the problem in a elegant way.

Comment: @TomDworzanski $_GLOBAL is an array anyway so it shouldn't be a problem to just pass the global into it

Comment: Yea exactly. Taking what @TonyDeStefano was doing with $GLOBALS and combining it with your approach, here's what I came up with: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33882176/636044

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `str_replace` to do this. Since you know what the place holders are going to be, try something like this:

```
str_replace(['{{domain}}','{{hostname}}'],[$domain, $hostname], $file_contents);
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in my question, I don't want the variable names to be hard-coded.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the work for global variables

```
<?php

$domain = 'example.com';
$hostname = 'www.' . $domain;
$file_contents = "127.0.0.1 {{domain}} {{hostname}}";

foreach($GLOBALS as $key => $value){

    if(!is_string($value) && !is_numeric($value)){
        continue;
    }

    $file_contents = str_replace('{{'.$key.'}}', $value, $file_contents);
}

var_dump($file_contents);
```

Will output:

```
string '127.0.0.1 example.com www.example.com' (length=37)
```